# java springdoc @ApiResponses how to define a List as return object using

Tags: java, spring-boot, springdoc

I'm using SpringBoot with the following dependency

> ```
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
>         <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
>         <version>1.5.12</version>
>     </dependency>
> ```

The controller class (@RestController) has one entry point (@GetMapping), and this entry point should return a List of the object  : **MyClass.java**. I added Swagger annotations above the method in order to create API documentation via a swagger UI page.

The swagger documentation should indicate that the return object is of type

> List< MyClass>

But how should I do that ? If I do

> "@Schema(implementation = List< MyClass >.class)"

there is a compile error.

**Swagger annotations:**

> ```
> @Operation(....)
> @ApiResponses(value = {
>         @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "successful operation",
>                 content = { @Content(mediaType = "application/json",
>                         schema = @Schema(implementation = ????)) }),
>         @ApiResponse(...),
>         @ApiResponse(...)
>
> @GetMapping(value = "/aaa", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
> public List<MyClass> getAaa(...)
> {
>     return ...
> }
> ```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use an [ArraySchema](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-2.X---Annotations#arrayschema) annotation for this and assign it to the `array` attribute instead of the `schema` attribute of the `@Content` annotation.
You don't need to specify `List.class` only its type parameter `MyClass.class`.

```
    @Operation(
            summary = "Get a list of users",
            description = "Get a list of users registered in the system",
            responses = {@ApiResponse(
                    responseCode = "200",
                    description = "The response for the user request",
                    content = {
                            @Content(
                                    mediaType = "application/json",
                                    array = @ArraySchema(schema = @Schema(implementation = User.class))
                            )
                    })
            }
    )
    @GET
    @SecurityRequirement(name = "JWT")
    @Path("/user")
    public List<User> getUsers() {
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: I used ArraySchema as suggested, and it works !  Many thanks.